# How to add XSL resource dynamically (programatically) in xslt-transformer?

Tags: xml, spring, xslt, spring-integration

I am using spring integration's **xslt-transfomer** for xml transformation.
My code is like below,

```
<int-xml:xslt-transformer id="xmlTransformer" input-channel="inputChannel" 
        output-channel="outputChannel"  xsl-resource="classpath:META-INF/OrderXslt.xsl" />
```

here I want to pass **xsl-resource="classpath:META-INF/OrderXslt.xsl"** dynamically at the runtime. I am able to get **xmlTransformer** bean from context but cant figure out how to set **xsl-resource** to it. My java code is like,

```
File myFile = new File("D:\OrderXslt.xsl");
EventDrivenConsumer transformerConsumer =  (EventDrivenConsumer) ctx.getBean("xmlTransformer");

//I need to pass myFile to transformerConsumer instace.
//However I am unable to find any API of EventDrivenConsumer 
            which will accept xsl resource form here (i.e. myFile )
```

Any programmatic explanation will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
    public class TempTransformer<Object, Obejct> extends AbstractTransformer  {

    private volatile XsltPayloadTransformer xslt;

    protected Object doTransform(Message<?> message) throws Exception {
        return (Object) findorBuildTransformerForMessage(message).transform(message); 
//Its throwing error here as
//org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: failed to transform message; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    }

    private Transformer findorBuildTransformerForMessage(Message<?> message{
    xslt = new XsltPayloadTransformer(new ClassPathResource("/META-INF/OrderXslt2.xsl"));
    return xslt;
    }
```

**EDIT**

I have implemented `XsltPayloadTransformer` the in the following way.

```
protected Message<?> doTransform(Message<?> message) throws Exception {
    xsltTransformer = new XsltPayloadTransformer(new ClassPathResource("D:/sample.xsl"));

    this.xsltTransformer.setResultType("StringResult");
    this.xsltTransformer.afterPropertiesSet();
    return this.xsltTransformer.transform(message);

    }
```

However I am not getting correct output. On the other hand I have a simple java program which uses Saxon implementation and shows correct output. Here it is...

```
 public static void main(String [] arr) {

    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    StreamSource xmlInputFile = new StreamSource("D:/input.xml");
    StreamSource xslTransformationFile = new StreamSource("D:/sample.xsl");
    StreamResult xmlOutputFile = new StreamResult(new File("D:/output.xml"));
    Transformer transformer;
    try {
        transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xslTransformationFile);  //gives instance of net.sf.saxon.jaxp.TransformerImpl 
        transformer.transform(xmlInputFile, xmlOutputFile);
    } 
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    }
```

I cant figure out what I am missing. Is there anything else I need to set to `XsltPayloadTransformer`?? Or I am missing on anything ?
 I am using **XSL v2** and **spring 4.1.7** and **spring integration 4.1.8** vesrions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 classes involved, the `EventDrivenConsumer`, the `MessageTransformingHandler` (a property `handler` of the consumer) and the `XsltPayloadTransformer` - the `transformer` property of the handler.

The `XsltPayloadTransformer` doesn't currently have an API to change the resource, it is provided in a constructor argument, so you'd have to create a new one.

The `MessageTransformingHandler` doesn't have an API to change the transformer - it's final and a constructor arg. So you'd have to create a new one.

The `EventDrivenTransformer` doesn't have an API to change the handler, it's final and a constructor arg.

So, the bottom line is you can't do what you want with the standard out-of-the-box consumer.

However, you can create your own bean that delegates to a `XsltPayloadTransformer` which you can replace with a new one as-needed. Just be sure that if you create the `XsltPayloadTransformer` programmatically, you must call `afterPropertiesSet()` because that's where the setup is completed.

The [API for the EventDrivenConsumer is here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/api/index.html?org/springframework/integration/endpoint/EventDrivenConsumer.html) but it won't help you for the reasons above.

You could also use the `Templates` option and write your own wrapper to dynamically change the resource.

**EDIT**

```
<int:transformer ... ref="myTransformer" />

public class Foo<Object, Object> extends AbstractTransformer<T, U> {

    private final ConcurrentMap<String, Transformer> xslts = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    protected Object doTransform(Message<?> message) throws Exception {

        return findorBuildTransformerForMessage(message).transform(message);
    }

    private Transformer findorBuildTransformerForMessage(Message<?> message) {
        // retrieve from map or create and add it to map
    }
}
```

Comment: @GarryRussell Thanks for the explanation, but still I am confused with delegation of XsltPayloadTransformer and how should I replace it with new one.

Comment: See my edit for an example, but I think I would use the templates approach.

Comment: @Garry I need a thread safe approach. What about using 
Transformer annotation is it a thread safe and can I use that implementation. ( please See the latest edit )

Comment: You should edit your question, not my answer but, no, adding `@Transformer` won't make it thread-safe there's one transformer instance. You'll need to maintain a `Map<String, XsltPayloadTransformer>` (probably a concurrent hash map) and, if a transformer with the desired resource is not in the map, create one and add it - that way it will be present for the next message that needs to use that resource.

Comment: @Garry I was trying to implement your solution but unable to find the API you have specified ablove i.e. `xslt.transformPayload(payload);` 
Yes there is another API `xslt.transform(Message<?>)` but its not working either. I am using 4.1.8 version of **Spring Integration**.

Comment: I have implemented it but now when I try to call transform() on Message I am getting error  `MessageTransformationException : failed to transform message; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`. See the edit in question to check the code.

Comment: You need to show the stack trace - and you really should use a map instead of creating a new one for each message. And, I told you that you need to call `afterPropertiesSet()` to initialize the transformer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Garry. It was my mistake, I wasn't calling afterPropertiesSet(). It worked after calling it.
Thanks again your support is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Garry, I have implemented the solution discussed and it's working. But however the output I am getting is not what I am expecting. On the other hand if I use Saxon for transformation then its correct. See my edit for further clarification.

Comment: You should ask a new question for this - it's not related to this question. Also `However I am not getting correct output` is insufficient - you need to show/describe the differences.